# Laravel pluck returns id value "0"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm learning Laravel. And now I am facing a problem that I have searched a solution for and haven't found. The Pluck method is returning the first id value from the DB as *0*. Shouldn't it be *1* ? Because of that, I can't use the first id value (it gives the error below).

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

And I have to pick from the second choice for it to work. I wonder if am doing something wrong. I am using Laravel 5.4.  This is the code:

#### Controller:

```
function orders(Request $request) {
    $modelesc = $request->modelesc;
    $robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Model', $modelesc)->get();
    $colours = DB::table('colours')->get()->pluck('Colour');
    return view('orders', compact('robots', 'colours'));
}

function storeorders(Request $request) {
    order::create($request->all());
}
```

#### View:

```
@foreach($robots as $robot)
  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST']) !!}
    Model: {!! Form::text('Model', $robot->Model) !!}<br><br>
    {!! Form::hidden('users_id', Auth::user()->id) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('Fabrication_date', date('Y-m-d')) !!}
    Choose colour: {!! Form::select('Colour_id', $colours) !!}<br><br>
    {!! Form::hidden('Order_status_id', '1') !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Order') !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only specify the field name to pluck, the results will be keyed as a normal 0-based array. In order to have the results keyed by the colour id from the database, you need specify the id column as the second argument to `pluck()`.

Assuming your colour ids are in the column `Colour_id` (based off of your form), your code should look like:

```
$colours = DB::table('colours')->pluck('Colour', 'Colour_id');
```

---

Note, I also removed the intermediate call to `get()`. While it will work both ways, not doing a `get()` first will keep you from building a collection of all your colours and then plucking from the collection. This saves some processing and memory.

Comment: It now works. Its returning the first value as "1". Thanks a lot